# Send an artifact (zip file) to source stage on AWS CodePipeline through Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

is there any way of sending a zip file made on a Jenkins job to an AWS CodePipeline Source Stage, so the build gets triggered and passed to CodeBuild with the artifact made on the Jenkins job?

Answer (score 1):

In your CodePipeline, create a source action (Action Provider->Source->Amazon S3) pointing to a s3 bucket (and prefix?) and place your zip file in the configured S3 location.